# Twig assuming punctuation/string when decimal not preceded with number value?

Tags: php, symfony, types, twig

**Consider the following:**

```
A) {{ form.vars.attr.dimensions.width * .1875 }}
B) {{ form.vars.attr.dimensions.width * 0.1875 }}
```

**Where** `form.vars.attr.dimensions.width` is an integer.

The following is a dump of `form.vars.attr.dimensions`.

```
array:2 [
  "width" => 1600
  "height" => 478
]
```

**Example A** will throw the following exception:

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ".".

**Example B** works correctly and outputs `300.0`.

I understand that it is most likely interpreting the value as a string, but my question would be **why**?  I would think that since it's unquoted, it shouldn't be seen as a literal.  I realize I can get around this with things like number_format, preceding zeros, etc. I'm just genuinely curious why Twig would not identify that decimal correctly.  Or maybe I'm missing something else.

**Furthermore**, the same logic applied in vanilla PHP does not produce this situation:

```
<?php
  $val = 1600;
  var_dump($val * .1875);
  // float(300)
?>
```

Comment: Most likely it's because of the Implementation of `twig`. You can see the full list on [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html). You need to scroll down a little towards *Implementation*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` in `.1875` has already been identified as a punctuation token in the first step of template rendering.

The Twig documentation covers this process in [Twig Internals](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/internals.html). In the first step:

> The lexer tokenizes a template source code into a token stream

In the documentation section [The Lexer](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/internals.html#the-lexer), it shows a way to convert some source code into a token stream. If we do that with your two examples:

```
$ex1 = '{{ form.vars.attr.dimensions.width * 0.1875 }}';
$ex2 = '{{ form.vars.attr.dimensions.width * .1875 }}';

$stream1 = $twig->tokenize(new Twig_Source($ex1, 'example1'));
$stream2 = $twig->tokenize(new Twig_Source($ex2, 'example2'));
```

The output is like this:

```
Example 1:               Example 2:

VAR_START_TYPE()         VAR_START_TYPE()
NAME_TYPE(form)          NAME_TYPE(form)
PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)      PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)
NAME_TYPE(vars)          NAME_TYPE(vars)
PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)      PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)
NAME_TYPE(attr)          NAME_TYPE(attr)
PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)      PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)
NAME_TYPE(dimensions)    NAME_TYPE(dimensions)
PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)      PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)
NAME_TYPE(width)         NAME_TYPE(width)
OPERATOR_TYPE(*)         OPERATOR_TYPE(*)
NUMBER_TYPE(0.1875)      PUNCTUATION_TYPE(.)     <----
VAR_END_TYPE()           NUMBER_TYPE(1875)
EOF_TYPE()               VAR_END_TYPE()
                         EOF_TYPE()
```

In the next step of the process, the parser tries to convert the token stream into a tree, and the punctuation token doesn't make sense after the operator which causes the error you're seeing.

As far as why the Twig lexer works that way in the first step, if you check [the source](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/lib/Twig/Lexer.php), the expression lexer steps through the input string, applying various regexes sequentially. The number regex is

```
'/[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?/A'
```

which doesn't match `.1875`, and in the subsequent step, the `.` is identified as punctuation.

This answer doesn't help if you're trying to figure out a way to get it to work with decimal numbers without leading zeroes, but it sounds like you're more interested in just understanding how it works, so hopefully this will be helpful.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! And yes it was more of a curiosity thing than trying to figure out  any sort of workaround.  Appreciate it!!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for asking an interesting question. :)